# How to set a global variable after a function finishing running?

Tags: python

For example, I have any function that is called `example()`, and it is running.

How to set a global variable `number = 1` only after `example()` finish running, before that, this variable shouldn't work?

I would be glad if you attached the code of how this can be implemented.

Comment: How about call the function first and then create the variable outside ?

Comment: @McLovin I need to set this variable only after this function finish running, before this variable shouldn't work

Comment: What does it means the variable shouldn't work? Variables don't do anything if you don't invoke them.

Comment: If "shouldn't work" means "isn't defined" then assigning the return value of the function is what you want. globals are bad, don't use them

Comment: add a `return 1` for exemple in the end of your function and assign your variable like this `variable=exemple()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@SitiSchu is absolutely right. Using global variables is bad form. Most likely you've built your program logic wrong. But if you really want to and I understand you correctly, use something like:

```
def example(a, b):
    ...
    global x
    x = True
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = None
    example(1, 2)
```